# How to find out if a std::vector in a string in cpp?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a string like `...hello...world...`, and I want to check if it is in some strings,so I split it by `...` and save it in a `<vector> string`,the problem is how to check both of item in input_str **sequentially**?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input_str1 = "Good morning, hello, a beautiful world";//true
    string input_str2 = "what a wonderful world, hello!"; //false, but I only can return true
    //item = "...hello...world..."
    vector<string> item;
    item.push_back("hello");
    item.push_back("world");
    bool status = false;
    for (auto sub_item : item)
    {
        cout << sub_item << ' ';
        if (input_str2.find(sub_item) != string::npos) //change str1 to str2 
            status = true;
        else
        {
            status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
     cout << status;
}
```

Checking `input_str1` works fine, but for `input_str2` the output should be `0` because the two words appear not in the right order. My code prints `1` for both.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, you'll need two vectors.
The first one containing your 'search phrases', the second one containing your 'phrases to be searched'. Once you've got that, it's a simple matter of doing two iterations and checking if the string has been found.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify what you have as input, what you expect as output and what the problem is with the code you wrote already?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt for example,checking if '...hello...world...' both in input string,  "Good morning, hello, a beautiful world",yes, second one, no, besides, "hello, my friend", "big world" both return no.

Comment: Initialize `bool status = true;` and remove `status = true;`. You start with the assumption that the string contains all words. Then, you iterate over the list of words and check each word. If a word doesn't exist, set `status = false;`. Don't set it back to `true`.

Comment: I get a "yes" for the code as expected https://godbolt.org/z/ccbs3x3Gf

Comment: whats wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number input_str2 should return false

Comment: why ? `input_str2` contains `"hello"` and `"world"`

Comment: not sequentially...llike I said in 1st paragraph @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: also the code you posted does not use `input_str2` please post a [mcve]  the one that does not work as expected and please include actual and expected output in the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is convenitent for me to change and test str1 to str2 directly

Comment: `find` returns the position where the string was found and it has an overload to choose at which position to start searching. Frankly this is merely an issue of ignoring documentation, because you have already all you need, you just need to use it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, I am novice in cpp, the main problem is checking sequentially and I did't get your answer.

Comment: Maybe `<regex>` is another option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include examples of matches and mismatches. Make small sentences. Start them with a capital letter and end them with a period. When I read your reply to me above, I can't make sense of this. I understand if it's hard in a foreign language, so maybe get help translating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `bool status = true;` and remove `status = true;`. You start with the assumption that the string contains all words. Then, you iterate over the list of words and check each word. If a word doesn't exist, set `status = false;`.

Store the position of the last result and start the next search at that position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input_str1 = "Good morning, hello, a beautiful world";//true
    std::string input_str2 = "what a wonderful world, hello!"; //false, but I only can return true
    //item = "...hello...world..."
    std::vector<std::string> item;
    item.push_back("hello");
    item.push_back("world");
    bool status = true;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    for (auto sub_item : item)
    {
        std::cout << sub_item << ' ';
        pos = input_str2.find(sub_item, pos);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
        {
            status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << status;
}
```

Output

```
hello world 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest Regular Expressions if it's ok with your assignment. It'd look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input_str1 = "Good morning, hello, a beautiful world";//true
    string input_str2 = "what a wonderful world, hello!"; //false, but I only can return true

    //item = "...hello...world..."
    const std::regex rxItems{"hello.*world"};
    const bool status = std::regex_search(input_str2, rxItems);

    cout << status;
}
```

This code searches for the strings "hello" and "world" in sequence, but accepts any characters (or even none) in between.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the position where the string was found and there is an overload that takes the position to start searching as paramter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool check(const std::string& input_str2) {
    vector<string> item;
    item.push_back("hello");
    item.push_back("world");
    size_t index = 0;
    for (auto sub_item : item)
    {
        cout << sub_item << ' ';
        index = input_str2.find(sub_item,index);
        if (index == string::npos) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    string input_str2 = "what a wonderful world, hello!"; //false, but I only can return true
    //item = "...hello...world..."
     cout << check(input_str2);
}
```

Better start with `status = true` because if `items` is empty then finding `0` items is always successful. Then there is no need to assign `true` when a word is found and when placed in a function the variable can be removed alltogether.